# Trying to install bootstrap checkbox and they do not appear

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am displaying permission page and i want the checkboxes to show like those: https://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-checkbox/#html-examples but it does not seem to be working on my case.

My code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Backend</title>
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#5bc0de" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="<?php echo Config::get('url/base_url'); ?>img/metis-tile.png" />

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Config::get('url/base_url'); ?>js/dist/js/bootstrap-checkbox.min.js" defer></script>
  </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Administrator Permissions</h2>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <?php foreach($array1 as $key => $value){?>
                            <br/><label><input type="checkbox" id="input-1" value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php if(Permissions::adminHasPermission($key)) {echo "checked";}?> /> <?php echo $value; ?></label>

                            <script>
                                $('#input-1').checkboxpicker({
                                  html: true,
                                  offLabel: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">',
                                  onLabel: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">'
                                });
                            </script>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <?php foreach($array2 as $key => $value){?>
                            <br/><label><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php if(Permissions::adminHasPermission($key)) {echo "checked";}?> /> <?php echo $value; ?></label>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <?php foreach($array3 as $key => $value){?>
                            <br/><label><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php if(Permissions::adminHasPermission($key)) {echo "checked";}?> /> <?php echo $value; ?></label>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <h2>Moderator Permissions</h2>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <?php foreach($array1 as $key => $value){?>
                            <br/><label><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php if(Permissions::moderatorHasPermission($key)) {echo "checked";}?> > <?php echo $value; ?></label>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <?php foreach($array2 as $key => $value){?>
                            <br/><label><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php if(Permissions::moderatorHasPermission($key)) {echo "checked";}?> > <?php echo $value; ?></label>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <?php foreach($array3 as $key => $value){?>
                            <br/><label><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php if(Permissions::moderatorHasPermission($key)) {echo "checked";}?> > <?php echo $value; ?></label>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

but still the style is not applied and they look like normal checkbox. Any ideas what i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" defer></script>` before you call :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

so it would look like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" defer></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

Comment: @BRG Did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in you code. I try to simplify it:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $checked = '';
    if (Permissions::adminHasPermission($key)) {
        $checked =  "checked";
    }
    ?>
    <br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="input-<?php echo $i; ?>" name="something[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?> /> <?php echo $value; ?></label>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>

<script>
 $(function() {

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').checkboxpicker({
        html: true,
        offLabel: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">',
        onLabel: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">'
    });
  })
</script>
```

First of all, do not put the script into the foreach. Do you really need it more times?

Second, use unique ID for HTML elements.

Third, add a name to it, and put `[]` at the end of the checkboxes, to be sure, it will posted as an array.

Fourth, put your script inside `$(function() { ... } );` to be sure, it will run on document ready.

Try it.

Comment: thanks a lot although i was asking a different thing.

Comment: I see, but this is so long for a comment. To be sure, everything is right, and to debug, where is the problem, the first step to remove the known bugs. So when you fixed these problems, just tell us, what is your actual result now.